# Panel data with small N. Is it ok to use "lme"?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, small-sample, lme4-nlme

I have longitudinal observations from 6 individuals. For each individual, there are 29 time points when data have been collected. Can I use "lme" in R to estimate a model?

Should I check for autocorrelations?

Thank you.
Berna

Additional notes: My data consist of caregiver-child conversations. I am interested in the usage of a grammatical morpheme over time both in child's speech and child-directed speech. There are 6 children in my data, who were observed between 8 and 36 months of age (monthly). I was thinking that I could use growth curve modeling to see whether the usage of this grammatical morpheme in child's speech changes over time (with random intercepts and slopes to view each child's own trajectory). I used some plots and I am assuming a linear trend. I am also hoping to analyze the data in a piecewise manner to see whether the slope will differ after a time point. Can I run this piecewise analysis per person only?

In addition, I am also interested how two variables would be related in time. Should I do a plain correlation analysis at first to see whether the two are related?

Comment: `lme` is just an R function, what kind of model do you have in mind for this data?

Comment: Hi Tim, I am wondering how some measurements change over time, so growth curve models I suppose.
Also I would like to know whether two variables are related over time.

Comment: Could you edit your question to go into more details about your data and your model? Unfortunately now it is pretty vague and so it is hard to answer.